# Access XRDP workspace from server

Tags: 14.04, remote-desktop, ubuntu-mate, xrdp

**Core Details**

- I've set up XRDP on my linux laptop.
- I've set up XRDP so it uses ubuntu mate when joined.
- I've sucessfully connected to my laptop from another computer.

**The Issue**

If I run a program via RDP, I have no way of finding it on the laptop. For example:

- On another computer I remote in to my laptop.
- I open a browser and exit my remote session.
- How can I find that open browser on my laptop?

I'm worried about remote processes not being properly closed and I end up with a bunch of unnecessary resource consumption.

Answer (score 0):

```
ps -aux | grep firefox
```

shows you output some what like this

```
myuser     6660  0.0  0.0  20836  3104 pts/1    S+   00:07   0:00 firefox
```

The first column will show you the user name , second column will show you the proccess id, and the last will show you the process name .

At last your Goal:

```
kill -9 6660
```